# Chemfig didn't put the bond in the correct atom

Tags: diagrams, chemfig

I'm trying to draw a simple molecule (isopropanol) with chemfig, marking the hydrogen atom attached to the oxygen in red.
But the bond is missplaced at the midle of the group OH, instead just below the oxygen atom.
This is the original code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=1.5em}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{-[:30](-[:90]O{\color{red}H})-[:-30]}
\end{document}
```

I'm try also to configure the bond attributes using the next code where I put the number 1 in the fourth position, but the result is the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=1.5em}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{-[:30](-[:90,,,1]O{\color{red}H})-[:-30]}
\end{document}
```

This is a picture of the molecule:

[image]

Could you be so nice to give me a tip for this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See section 12.1  of the ChemFig manual https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=1.5em}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{-[:30](-[:90]O|{\color{red}H})-[:-30]}
\end{document}
```

[image]